# Django model internationalization

Tags: django, django-models, internationalization

What is the best way to have model fields translated in Django? I've thought about adding extra fields to the model (one field per language) or creating another model with all texts in every language, is there a recommended way to achieve that?

Thank you very much

Comment: look for packages that do that for you: django-modeltranslation and django-vinaigrette. The first one uses extra fields (hidden behind the scenes), the second one uses .po files with gettext. I personally prefer the database fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NB : I first voted to close this as primarily opinion based but then it struck me that there were actually technical reasons to choose one solution or the other...*

Both approach are valid and as a matter of fact you'll find reusable django apps based on either one of the other.

Technically, there are pros and cons to each design.

Using distinct "translation" objects means you'll have an additional join or query (to get both the "master" model and it's translation(s)), but you have no overhead on the master model itself (without translation). Also, it makes create/update operations more complicated.

Using additional "hidden" per-language fields avoids the join / additional query overhead and keeps create/update operation simple, but makes records much bigger so it has some overhead wrt/ the database itself (page cache management etc) and the volume of data going back and forth between your django process and the database.

As a general rule, if you have to support a lot of languages and/or have to translate a lot of text fields for each model, you'll probably want to use a distinct model for translations, while if you have few languages and only a couple "translatable" fields per model the "hidden field" approach will be simpler to implement and will avoid the extra queries / joins.

As far as I'm concerned, I've had experience with both solutions and found the "hidden field" solution (using `django-modeltranslations`) to work fine for our current needs (four languages supported and we should not get  much more, no more than =~ four translatable fields per model, and those models are rarely updated so we can cache aggressively if needed), but you may have totally different needs.

In all cases, don't even try implementing this from scratch, use one of the existing django apps instead, it will save you a lot of time and pain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I've been reading django-modeltranslations documentation, and I have one doubt about that. Can I use it if I have models already created? Because I've read (https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html#committing-fields-to-database) that makemigrations will not automatically work with models already created, so I'm not sure if it will be confortable to use then.

Comment: You're not reading the doc correctly. Makemigrations works just fine on already existing models, __provided that those models live in one of your own apps__ . The only issue is when you want to add translation support to 3rd part apps, and it's only an issue because the migration would then be added to the 3rd part app's source code (which means you'd have to fork it and maintain the fork) - and then you can use the provided `sync_translation_fields` command instead. FWIW and as far as I can remember I only ever used modeltranslations on already existing models ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Check out their docs [django translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation)

This will help too 
[Localization: How to Create Language Files - Python Django Tutorials](https://djangobook.com/localization-create-language-files/)

Comment: The user asks about __models__ translations.